# Swift Closures: Must Capture Lists Be Exhaustive?

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management, closures

Suppose I have a Swift class like this:

```
@objc final MyClass : NSObject
{
    let classPropertyString = "A class property"


    func doStuff() 
    {
        let localString = "An object local to this function"

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [classPropertyString] in
             // Do things with 'classPropertyString' and 'localString'
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: when I write a capture list, am I responsible for **EXHAUSTIVELY** listing all the things to which I want the closure to hold a strong reference?

In other words, if I omit `localString` from my capture list (as I've done here), will the closure still automatically capture a strong reference to it or am I in for a bad time?

Comment: Although Apple does not discuss this "define what items should be strongly captured in the capture list" approach in their docs (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID56), I've seen it done in various places and am wondering about the semantics. Hence this question. I RTFM.

Comment: not related to your question but is Swift naming convention to name all classes starting with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several minor quirks with your question that make it tricky to answer clearly, but I think I understand the underlying concern, and the short answer is "no." But your example is impossible, so the answer is "it's impossible." And if it were possible, there'd be no strong reference (nor would there be a need for one), so the question still would be kind of "it's impossible." Even so, let's walk through what's going on here.

First, `closure` can't reference `localString` unless it's reassigned somehow in the comment inside `doStuff()`. `closure` is assigned at a level where `localString` is not in scope. Closures can only capture variables that are in scope when they are assigned, not when they're called. But let's go back to the original version of this question, before it was edited. That version did have the case you're describing:

```
@objc final myClass : NSObject
{
    let classPropertyString = "A class property"


    func doStuff() 
    {
        let localString = "An object local to this function"

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [classPropertyString] in // (1)
             // Do things with 'classPropertyString' and 'localString'
        }
        // (2)
    }
}
```

There's no problems here. `classPropertyString` is copied into the closure, avoiding any retain loops. `localString` is referenced by the closure, and so it's preserved as long as the closure exists.

Because you listed `classPropertyString` in the capture list, it is evaluated at point (1) and copied into the closure. Because you implicitly captured `localString`, it is treated as a reference. See [Capture Lists](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html) in the Swift Programming Language Reference for some excellent examples of exactly how this works in different cases.

In no case (*) will Swift allow the underlying storage for something you're using in a closure to disappear behind your back. That's why the typical concern is excessive retains (memory leaks) rather than dangling references (crashes).

(*) "In no case" here is a lie. There are several ways that Swift will allow it, but almost all of them involve "Unsafe" which is your warning about that. The major exception is `unowned`, and of course anything involving `!` types. And Swift is not typically thread-safe, so you need to be careful about that...

The last comment about thread-safety is a place where the subtle distinctions between implicit and explicit captures can really matter. Consider this case where you modify an implicitly captured value on two queues:

```
func doStuff() -> String
{
    var localString = "An object local to this function"

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
         localString = "something else"
         callFunction(localString)
    }

    localString = "even more changes"
    return localString
}
```

What happens in that case? Good grief, never do that. I *believe* it's undefined behavior and that localString could be *anything* including corrupted memory, at least in the most general case (it might be defined behavior for calling `.async`; I'm not sure). But don't do it.

But for your normal cases, there is no reason to explicitly capture local variables. (I sometimes wish Swift had gone the C++ way and said it *was* required, but it isn't.)

Ok, one more way implicit and explicit are different that might drive home how they work. Consider a stateful closure like this (I build these pretty often):

```
func incrementor() -> () -> Int {
    var n = 0
    return {
        n += 1
        return n
    }
}

let inc = incrementor()
inc()  // 1
inc()  // 2
inc()  // 3

let inc2 = incrementor()
inc2() // 1
```

See how the local variable `n` is captured by the closure, and can be modified after it goes out of scope. And see how `inc2` has its own version of that local variable. Now try that with explicit capture.

```
func incrementor() -> () -> Int {
    var n = 0
    return { [n] in // <---- add [n]
        n += 1      // Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'n' is an immutable capture
        return n
    }
}
```

Explicit captures are copies and they're immutable. Implicit captures are references, and so have the same mutability as the thing they reference.

Comment: Ummm... question: In the first example, specifying [classPropertyString] in a capture list will in fact copy the value as it was the point in time the closure is instantiated. However, from my understanding localString will not be *copied*, but bound to the closure via reference semantics, as it's not specified as an explicit capture. This is regardless of the fact that it's a value type (see first n example) and the fact that it's a let constant.

Comment: Thanks for the really thorough walkthrough; that was fantastic. I've rolled back to the original example even though I understand why using GCD isn't going to create a retain cycle. As you can tell, I'm a longtime C/ObjC developer moving over to Swift, so I'm still getting my bearings on the finer points.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for the comments. I've edited (mostly just deleted sentences that were inaccurate.)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelLong. Edited.